# UUID Auto field for Custom field

Tags: custom-fields, api

I want to create something like a UUID field for a custom multi-value fieldset that I will consume from an external API call.

In other words: I have contacts that can have multiple versions of a custom field-set and I want a way to uniquely identify the subset after it leaves CIVI. A custom field that auto-generated a unique identifier would be ideal. I could manually create the identifier but that seems somewhat sub-optimal.

Is this something that is possible with CIVICRM?